# .htaccess is renaming my css, img, and js

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I am trying to route a single blog post from a url

The url looks like this : `http://localhost/news/post/1/post-title-slug`

And my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`
```

And my routing file I am currently using a library called `nezamy/route`

```
$route->get('/post/?/?', function($postid,$page) {
    include 'post.php';
});
```

When I do this my `css`, `js` and `images` is renamed as well to something like this: `http://localhost/news/post/1/css/main.css`

Comment: That is because you load the css, js files from the relative location. You need to make a function to get the base url taking the rewritten path as a parameter and load css, js files from that base path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the css/js files with their absolute location when using htaccess rewrites. To do this, you can define your base url in a php variable as shown below:

```
$base_url = 'http://localhost/';
```

and then refer to it where you call the css/js files like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>css/main.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Prateek's answer is good, but I solve similar problem by adding.

```
<base href="/"/>
```

in my head tag.

or you can experiment with different folder like:

```
<base href="/web/"/>
```

and etc.